# How do I populate socket address properly?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm sending a ICMP packet through a socket in iOS:

```
struct sockaddr         hostAddress;

self->hostAddress.sa_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "173.194.67.93", &self->hostAddress.sa_data);
```

Then, I open the socket and I send the packet:

```
bytesSent = sendto(
                   CFSocketGetNative(self->_socket),
                   [packet bytes],
                   [packet length],
                   0,
                   &self->hostAddress,
                   sizeof(self->hostAddress)
                   );
```

When I see the packet in WireShark, it's being sent to "67.93.0.0", instead to "173.194.67.93".

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Why is this tagged as so many languages?

Comment: Because the socket is opened and created in C, all the methods but one are in C

Comment: And that one that isn't C is a C#/C++/Objective-c method??? You gave a good reason to tag it as C, what about the rest?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a more high level library like boost asio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, ...);
```

should take a `struct in_addr` as the 3rd argument (see [docs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html)).

You're giving it `sa_data`, from

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

which is really treated as:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};
```

So, the first 16 bits are going in the port, the second 16 bits of the IPV4 address are actually making it into `sin_addr`, and the rest appears to be zero-initialized.

---

You *should* be doing this (I'll put loads of casts in for clarity)

```
struct sockaddr *addr = &self->hostAddress; // generic address
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)addr; // downcast to ipv4
inet_pton(AF_INET, "173.194.67.93", &ipv4->sin_addr);
```

Comment: Thanks, and how could I do it using a sockaddr struct?

Comment: NB. the clue was that the address you observed with wireshark looks like the right value shifted 16 bits - after that I just double-checked the docs

Comment: It works, just a thing, the last line is &ipv4->sin_addr, let me edit it

Comment: And I was so close! Thanks for fixing :)